# Sans-serif references in captions

Tags: captions, sans-serif

I use a serif font for my document (koma-script document class scrbook) but a sans-serif font for captions. If I reference, e.g. an equation, within my caption, this number is printed in serif, not sans-serif. How can I change that?

MWE using MinionPro (serif) and MyriadPro (sans-serif):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{array}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

An equation:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:eq1}
E=\hbar\omega \, .
\end{align}

\begin{table}
    \centering\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
    \begin{tabular}{ c >{\centering}m{6.0cm} c }
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    Band & Angular Momentum Eigenstate & Basis Set \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    a & b & c \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Values computed by Eq.~\eqref{eq:eq1} (0.1).}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\eqref` tries quite hard to set the font to `\normalfont`. Why don't you use `Eq.~\ref{eq:eq1}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, didn't know that `\eqref` tries so hard... Just is my usual workflow to spare the braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can go either of two routes:

- Add the instruction

  ```
  \renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
  ```

after the start of the `table` environment. As @UlrikeFischer has pointed out in a comment, `\eqref` sets its argument in `normalfont`, requiring the change in the "default font family" to get the desired font when using `\eqref`.

- Don't use `\eqref` in the first place. I suggest you load the `cleveref` package (with the option `capitalize`, if you prefer) and write the caption as

  ```
  \caption{Values computed by \cref{eq:eq1}.}
  ```

(I would like to provide the output of an MWE. Unfortunately, my TeX distribution doesn't seem to feature the `MinionPro` and `MyriadPro` packages featured in the OP's example.)